# How to fix flickering from css keyframe animation

Tags: html, css, sass, css-animations, keyframe

I am trying to stagger the opacity (fade) of three boxes via an infinite keyframe animation and the animation-delay property.

I am getting some unexpected behavior, as the third box fades away, it suddenly reappears faintly ("flickers") before the animation starts again. I am experiencing this across browsers.

I would like to use pseudo elements if possible, is there a known fix for this keyframe bug?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="child">  
   <div></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.container {
     position: fixed;
     left: 150px;
     top: 50px;

.child {
     position: absolute;
     animation:mymove 1s infinite;

     &::before{
         display: block;
         position: absolute;
         width: 25px;
         height: 25px;
         background-color: red;
         content: "";
         right: 40px;
         animation: inherit;
         animation-delay: .15s;
    }

    div {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        background-color: red;
        animation: inherit;
        animation-delay: .30s;
     }

     &::after{
         display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        background-color: red;
        content: "";
        left: 40px;
        bottom: 0px;
        animation: inherit;
        animation-delay: .45s;
       }
   }
}

 @keyframes mymove {
      0% {
      opacity: 1;
    }

      100% {
        opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7drzp8dy/)

Comment: I studied both variants and as I can see, they behave the same. If your non-pseudo version doesn't, you need to post that code sample too ... here is mine https://jsfiddle.net/gfrd06te/1/

Comment: You're right, I was mistaken... Are you seeing the flicker on the third element? I see it in your example as well.

Comment: It is actually on all of them, though it is most visible o the 3rd, which is understandable as it has the longest delay. I will have a look soon, to see how that could be avoided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason they *flicker* is because you have set an animation on their parent, the `child`.

And since its animation doesn't have a delay, it starts before its children, but will then be overridden by them as soon as their delay has passed, hence one can see a quick flash.

The best way to avoid any future issue with this, is to remove the animation from the `child`

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 150px;
  top: 50px;
}

.container .child {
  position: absolute;
}

.container .child::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  content: "";
  right: 40px;
  animation: mymove 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.15s;
}

.container .child div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: mymove 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.container .child::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  content: "";
  left: 40px;
  bottom: 0px;
  animation: mymove 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.45s;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, insight. It now makes sense. Thank you!